# std::vector as a template function argument

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector

I want to make a class method that takes a std::vector reference as an argument and I want to use it with different types of data.

The function should look like:

```
void some_function(const std::vector & vect){ //do something with vector }
```

and I want use it with for example:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
some_function(v1);
std::vector<string> v2;
some_function(v2);
```

I hope that I made my point clear.
Do I have to make a template method like that:

```
template<class T>
void some_function(std::vector<T> & vect){}
```

or can I do it in another way? If I have to, please tell me how I can write that method in a class.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: What's wrong with you suggested?

Comment: The answer to this question is self sufficient. Just to add that if anyone want to iterate such vectors then use : `for(typename vector<T, A>::const_iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The right way for a `template` function to accept any `std::vector` by `const&` is:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void some_func( std::vector<T,A> const& vec ) {
}
```

the second argument is the "allocator", and in some advanced usage of `std::vector` it will not be the default one.  If you just accept `std::vector<T>`, your `some_func` will reject `std::vector`s with alternative allocators.

Now, there are other ways to approach this that I will list quickly.  I will list them in decreasing cost:benefit ratio -- the one above is probably what you want, and the next one is sometimes useful, and after that I will branch off into over engineered cases that are rarely worth considering (but might be useful in some corner cases).

You could accept an arbitrary type `T` by `T&&` then test to determine if `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` is a kind of `std::vector`.  This would allow you to do "perfect forwarding" of the incoming `std::vector`.  It would also let you change the predicate you use to test to accept more than just a `std::vector`: for the most part, `const&` to `std::vector` probably just needs some arbitrary random-access container.

A ridiculously fancy way would be to do a two-step function.  The second step takes a type-erased random-access range view (or just a range-view if you don't need random access) for a fixed type `T` with SFINAE to ensure that the incoming object is compatible, the first step deduces the container type of the passed in type and calls the second step in a SFINAE context (`auto some_func(...)->decltype(...)`).

As type erasure of `std::vector<T> const&` to a random-access range view of contiguous `T`s doesn't lose much functionality, an advantage would be that you could guarantee that the body of your function is exactly the same for `std::vector<T> const&` and for `T[n]` and for `std::array<T,n>`.

It isn't a big advantage, especially for the boilerplate required.

[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) may make this much easier, because the multi-step SFINAE above will collapse into a few requires clauses.

Comment: Hey, I think that if I write like **template<typename T>
void some_func( T container ) {}** This code is also valid, right?

Comment: @codosopher `some_func( T const& container )` if you don't want to copy it yes.  But this won't constrain the argument to be a `std::vector`.

Comment: Well, I think that the only difference between `some_func( T& container )` and `some_func( std::vector<T>& container )` will be that it limits performing operations specific to std::vector.

Comment: *But this won't constrain the argument to be a std::vector.* what do you mean by that. If you mean that it won't accept vector as a parameter, I applied it and it runs.

Comment: @codosopher A parameter is *constrained* to a category *X* if things outside of the category *X* are not accepted as arguments.  To constrain is to restrict.  `T& container` will take things that are not container or vectors and attempt to compile the body of the template; if that succeeds (by happenstance or design) it will go forward.  The ones that constrain the argument will only accept vectors (or, in other cases, container) that pass whatever the constraint requirement is.